# PreparedStatment with a Left Join

Tags: java, prepared-statement, left-join

I am not sure if it is possible, but I want to create an insert query for a prepared-statement where the insert query consist of a join between two tables.

E.g. (perhaps a stupid example)

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_A A (" + 
             "GenderId, Name, Surname, Age) VALUES (B.GenderId, ?, ?, ?) " + 
             "LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.GenderId = B.GenderId " + 
             "WHERE B.Gender = 'Male'";

PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, "Bill");
statement.setString(2, "Gates");
statement.setInt(3, 50);
```

Comment: There is no such SQL syntax, regardless of the use of `PreparedStatement`s. What exactly are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve you can use a SELECT statement to generate the values you want to insert.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (GenderId, Name, Surname, Age)
SELECT b.GenderId, ?, ?, ? FROM TABLE_B B
WHERE b.Gender = 'Male'
```

There's some basic reading on the subject [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: That seems to be working except that I am getting and error "The statement did not return a result set". Despite this error the records are still being inserted. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't see from your example code, but possibly because you are using statement.executeQuery(). This expects a results set to be returned. If this is the case you could try statement.execute().
This is used when you're executing SQL that isn't expected to return anything (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/etc)

Comment: I did indeed have statement.executeQuery().  statement.execute() did solved the problem. Thank you.